# Arithmetic functions of particular type

Tags: analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

Any there any natural functions real valued single variable that:

**changes (increases) values  only at primes but otherwise stay constant** (like a non periodic increasing staircase)?

**whose increase in value at primes depend on the value of the primes** (and hence the increases are also irregular like the spacing of the staircase).

**the magnitude of jumps reduces/increases with increasing primes**.

So I am not looking for summation of delta functions at primes.

Would **there be any utility of such a natural function to number theory**?

Question: How does irregularity of primes contribute to errors using any counting function? What characteristic does one need in the counting function to reduce estimate errors?

Comment: For example, the sum of the primes $\le x$?

Comment: The error in counting primes is due to their irregularity.  $\psi(x)\sim \theta(x)$ even though one counts prime powersand the other does not.

Comment: @daniel could you explain how irregularity shows up as error in counting functions? Like what characteristics of the counting function does one need to reduce the error?

Comment: The error in counting functions is *entirely* due to irregularity of the primes. We try to use functions whose behavior we know to approximate the behavior of primes. Maybe what you are asking is too broad?

Answer (score 1):

There are exact formulas for various *weighted* prime counting functions. One of them is [Chebyshev's prime counting function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function)
$$
\psi_0(x) = x - \sum_{\rho} \frac{x^{\rho}}{\rho} - \frac{\zeta'(0)}{\zeta(0)} - \frac{1}{2} \log (1-x^{-2})
$$

The sum is taken over the non-trivial zeros $\rho$ of the zeta function. This is a staircase-like function, with jumps at the primes and prime powers.

Comment: This is close to what I am thinking except it jumps at prime powers. What is its utility?

Comment: @Turbo IIRC it is analytically simpler to work with than the actual prime counting function $\Pi(x)$. Plus, the "error" in counting prime powers in addition to primes is asymptotically 0.

Comment: do you have a link for this counting functionality? I would be interested in knowing exactly how it works.

Comment: @Turbo See http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Analytic-Number-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/1441928057

Comment: Question: So does the error in counting primes come from the fact that there is no better way to detect difference between $p$ and $p^k$ in counting formulas? As you say the machinary overcounts?

Comment: @Turbo That question on discerning primes from prime powers is best asked to a number theorist.

Comment: This is really von Mangoldt's formula. $\psi_0(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ are not the same.

Comment: Also this function does not satisfy the criteria that the magnitude of jumps reduces/increases.

Answer (score 1):

Chebyshev's $\vartheta$ function might work.

$$\vartheta(x)= \sum_{p\leq x} \log p. $$

It does not jump at prime powers and does not require calculation of $\rho.$

The counting function that Chebyshev worked with is

$\psi(x) = \sum \Lambda (x)$ in which $\Lambda(x)$ counts powers of primes.

This is different from von Mangoldt's formula $\psi_0(x)$ although they are closely related. Von Mangoldt's formula is $\psi(x)-\Lambda(x)$ at prime powers and $\psi(x)$ otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, I remembered that the counting formula given by von Mangoldt also counted prime powers but obviously that was later than Chebyshev. Please feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: @daniel nice answer. So how does irregularity step into error terms?

Comment: Does the jumping of $\vartheta(x)$ reduce as $x$ increases or inrease as $x$ increases?

Answer (score 0):

There is also the prime counting function:

$$\pi(x)=|\{p\,\mathrm{prime} : p\le x\}|.$$

Comment: Since the change in value at primes is always +1 for $\pi(x)$, it seems this doesn't (in spirit) meet the requirement that "increase in value at primes depend[s] on the value of the prime" and "I am not looking for summation of delta functions at primes".

Comment: Yes. Quite right. I didn't read the question carefully enough.

Comment: Of course it does have the advantage of being *natural* and interesting!

Comment: You can easily fix your example by composing an increasing function $f$ with $\pi(x)$ (although the OP seems a little ambivalent about whether strictly increasing is the only case of interest).

Comment: That does seem like a cheap way out. Especially since some good answers have already been posted.